# how to differentiate elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have few images which I need to zoom little bit (using CSS i.e. `transform : scale(1.2);`) on onMouseEnter and revert on onMouseLeave.
I have below code which is working.

CSS:-

```
.style {
    transform : scale(1.2);
    transition: transform .5s ease-out;
}

.shrink {
    transform : scale(1);
    transition: transform .5s ease-out;
}
```

Variable Declared in constructor:-

```
this.state = { 
            isHovered: false
        };
```

JS Method:-

```
handleHover(){
        this.setState({
            isHovered: !this.state.isHovered
        });
    }
```

logical op in render method:-

```
const imgClass = this.state.isHovered ? 'profile-pic style' : 'profile-pic shrink';
```

And two images:-

```
   <Image title ='one' src="pics/pic1.png" circle className={imgClass}  
    onClick={ () => this.props.methodRef('one')} height="70" width="100"     
onMouseEnter={this.handleHover} onMouseLeave={this.handleHover}/>

     <Image title ='two' src="pics/pic2.png" circle className={imgClass}  
    onClick={ () => this.props.methodRef('two') } height="70" width="100"     
onMouseEnter={this.handleHover} onMouseLeave={this.handleHover}/>
```

This code is working perfectly as I am expecting it to be. But the problem is both the images are zooming in and out at the same time.

How can I differentiate mouse movement over different-different elements in ReactJs.

Comment: Are you setting your classnames correctly? `profile-pic, style` supposed to be without a comma, right? If it so, and the classnames are set, it will be working perfectly

Comment: I tried removing comma but no change. Its still behaving the same. But thanks  for identifying wrong code.

Comment: you need to move handleHover and isHovered state inside the image component, this way their internal isHovered will change and only one Image will zoom. Right now you're using the same state for both Images, so both Images are zooming.

Comment: Image is one of the component given by React. I did not create that Component.

Comment: @Jaikrat Image is one of the component given by React. Any reference? It would be new finding for me as if react provides a component called Image.

Comment: Sure...I have one import like... `import { Image} from 'react-bootstrap';`

Comment: Ah, glad to know. You didn't mentioned it's react-bootstrap already.

Comment: @Jaikrat Can you once try: `{() => this.handleHover()}`

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar. No, Both the images are getting zoomed in and out at the same time.

Comment: @Jaikrat I couldn't find any issue with your code though, you may try using console what's going on there..

Comment: Nothing wrong in console...except warning related to unused imports. I know my code is wrong... I am sharing one variable among elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the Image components into one of your own that you can control and add states to. Or maybe another way would be to have an array in your parent component like:

```
state: {
    images:[{id: "image1", isHovered: false},
            {id:"image2", isHovered: false}]
}
```

So you can have your ids in the components:

```
<Image id={this.state.images[0].id} ...rest />
```

then handleHover:

```
handleHover(e) => {
    const images = [...this.state.images]; //copy your array
    const index = images.findIndex(el => (el.id === e.target.id));
    images[index].isHovered = !images[index].isHovered;
    this.setState({images});
}
```

This is overly complex, though. You should wrap it inside another component and manage state from there.

Comment: Not required. There's no issue using single state.

Comment: I think both images are zooming because he's using the same state for both. It doesn't matter which Image he hovers, both are watching for a single isHovered state, and both images are toggling classes

Comment: I said No. Not required. It's component not element. A bootstrap component.

Comment: I have to disagree here. Unless `isHovered` is an internal state of a component that we don't know about. Then he needs more than a single state to toggle classes

Comment: `You should wrap it inside another component and manage state from there.` => Yep.